# How i can call to method ids.setSchema from android?

Tags: android, gigya

I need call method ids.setAccountInfo, for this i must call method  ids.setSchema, but

> Note: For security reasons this method is not available for client side SDKs, only for server side SDKs.

How i can do it, if i don't use server sdk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ids.setSchema is an administrative API call to configure the database schema on your Gigya API key. For this reason you only need to call it when you want to add a new field to your data schema or modify the permissions on existing fields. For security reasons it can only be called server-side with your secret key and should not be made from a client-side environment.

If you don't have a server-side language to make the ids.setSchema API call, you can make a simple cURL request to the Gigya endpoints and pass your apiKey and secret key as URL parameters.

Here's a tool to make the request: https://www.hurl.it. You'll want to use https://ids.us1.gigya.com/ids.setSchema as your destination (swap out us1 with your API key's data center if necessary) and then include "apiKey", "secret", and any other method parameters such as "profileSchema" or "dataSchema" in the request.